# column ordering with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello please, i have this SIMPLE code of `twitter bootstrap` and would like to be helped :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-*-*">.....</div>    //column 1
  <div class="col-*-*">.....</div>    //column 2
  <div class="col-*-*">.....</div>    //column 3
</div>
```

What can i do so that when displaying them i change the order of display,i.e. column 2 is displayed at the left,column 1 at the center, column 3 can remain in its position.

Comment: instead of changing the column display order.have you thought of ordering the content inside it according to column order.

Comment: I have already written a lumpsum of content and i think i will get confused by quotes from php when i try to change the content to print out. if i knew what to add to change column order, it would be simpler rather than start *risk* copy-pasting code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [push and pull](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) from the grid of twitter, from that code the layout will change from `1,2,3` to `2,1,3`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4">.....</div>    //column 1
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-4">.....</div>    //column 2
  <div class="col-lg-4">.....</div>    //column 3
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is useful and it really did the trick. Thanks rockStar. I am new to stackoverflow and i have 10 reputation whereas the minimum reputation to vote up is 15; hope to gain more. Thanks for assistance